# Javafx : How I can add unique Elements into Listview (i.e Duplicate Element Get Skipped)

Tags: javafx

I am new to use javafx i want to use list with unique element in javafx how i can manage it . Display the Content of List view should be unique duplicates value get skipped. 
thank you

```
static ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
static ObservableList<String> bamitems = FXCollections
        .observableArrayList();

static ListView<String> list;
static ListView<String> listforbam;

public static void test() throws Exception {
    HBox root = new HBox();
    VBox yesaccordion = new VBox();

    Accordion acc = new Accordion();
    acc.getPanes().addAll(createPanes());
    yesaccordion.getChildren().add(acc);

    root.getChildren().addAll(yesaccordion);
    jfxpanel.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 100));
    panel.add(jfxpanel);
    items.addAll(LoadVCFFileToTrack.destitemlist);
    bamitems.addAll(LoadVCFFileToTrack.destitemBamlist);


    if (LoadVCFFileToTrack.destitemBamlist.size() > 0) {
        listforbam = new ListView<String>();
        listforbam.setItems(bamitems);
    }
    if (LoadVCFFileToTrack.destitemlist.size() > 0) {
        list = new ListView<String>();
        list.setItems(items);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) or better an [`ObservableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableSet.html) to store the items you want to display in the ListView.

To add the set to the list view you can use [`FXCollections.observableArrayList(Collection col)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-java.util.Collection-) method. It will convert the `ObservableSet` to `ObservableArrayList`.

```
listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(observableSet));
```

**Complete example**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        ObservableSet<String> observableSet = FXCollections.observableSet();
        //Item1 is repeated twice
        observableSet.addAll(Arrays.asList("Item1","Item2","Item3", "Item1"));
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(observableSet));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(listView, 200, 200));
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: how to add the observableset to ListView

Comment: @ltachiUchiha : we can add Arraylist to Listview i had seen various example and lots ofdigging on internet i didnot get any example with ObservableSet to add Content to List view Could you tell me , how  i can do this .....how to add the observableset to ListView

Comment: I have already added the code. The set works similar to list and doesn't contain duplicate items.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha will the `ObservableList` update if the `ObservableSet` is changed?